# when Open notification to intent activity when app is closed on android

Tags: android, push-notification

I use the code below to open notification to intent activity  when app closed, but it crash while get notification.
Please help me! 
It is my first time in stackoverflow question.

```
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.app.Application;

public class Myapplication extends Application {
    private String SENDER_ID="1048363856500";
    private String PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID="541a3e411d0ab1a4018b45b5";

    public void onCreate(){
    Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID,PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID);
    Pushbots.getInstance().setMsgReceiver(customHandler.class);
    super.onCreate();
    }
```